# get variable form view and use it in the external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Loading a Data to the view From My Controller.
I have to send that data for jquery autocomplete in external js file.

This is how I send the data to the view from the controller.

```
$this->load->view('myViewPage', ['dataForJs' => $dataforJs]);
```

In View, I use this dataForJs and declare the js variable to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataForJs= "<?=  $dataForJs?>";
  console.log(dataForJs); //I don't get data in console.
</script>
```

In External Js

```
    $('#autocomplete').devbridgeAutocomplete({
      lookup: dataForJs,  // Here I want that data but didn't get it.     
      minChars: 1,
      onSelect: function (suggestion) {
          $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data.category);
      },
      showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
      noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results',
      groupBy: 'category'
    });
```

I am looking for Similar Problem but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: try once `"<?php   echo $dataForJs;?>";`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have tried this sir but get same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks Like, It's Single Double Inverted Comma Problem.

Try this.

```
var dataForJs= <?=  $dataForJs?>;
```

Comment: Let me Try It.  I am not sure about it.